# Get IQueryable data using group by in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable

```
var q = from n in CS.trackers
group n by n.Id into g
select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Above is the code for getting the distinct records from DB. I wan the above record in `IQueryable` like below.

```
var Details = (from Track in CS.trackers
where Track.system.Id == Track.Id
select new ClassTracker
{
    Id = Track.Id,
    SystemId = Track.SystemId,
});

Details .AsQueryable();
```

How can I convert the 1st code to return as IQueryable as second of `ClassTracker`

Comment: You're using `.FirstOrDefault()` why would you want to query a single (or null) entity?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove `.FirstOrDefault()` ? :)

FirstOrDefault returns (max) single element

Answer (score 0):

Change `FirstOrDefault` to `Take(1)`

```
select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTime).Take(1);
```

Comment: I did that. but how to convert it to a class of IQueryAble.?